# What is the issue with "FIELDS TERMINATED BY" and "LINES TERMINATED BY"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

So I have created a mysql table called specs and I want to import into this table a csv file.

```
CREATE TABLE specs (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Brand` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `Horsepower` INT NOT NULL,
  `Range` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

The csv data looks like the following

```
ID\Brand\Horsepower\Range
1\Mercedes Benz\237\634
2\Audi\345\567
3\Ford\190\456
4\BMW\278\547
5\Toyota\123\364
6\Fiat\90\289
7\Daihatsu\120\450
8\Jeep\500\670
9\Seat\119\289
10\Mitsubishi\78\410
```

And this is how I import the data, but the table is filled with zeros. Where is the issue. I think the problem is something with FIELDS and LINES TERMINATED BY.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/anilyelin/Desktop/cars.csv'
INTO TABLE specs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

The output looks like the following:

```
mysql> select * from specs;
+----+-------+------------+-------+
| Id | Brand | Horsepower | Range |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
|  1 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  2 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  3 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  4 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  5 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  6 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  7 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  8 |       |          0 |     0 |
|  9 |       |          0 |     0 |
| 10 |       |          0 |     0 |
+----+-------+------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Definitely use an other symbol, not backslash ` \ `.  Maybe `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\'`if NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES was set (unlikely).

Comment: CSV is not standardized, but even so, it's highly unusual to use a backslash as the separator. Best to get whoever is generating this to use a comma or tab to separate them. If you can't do that I would experiment with the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` sql mode as mentioned by @JoopEggen or else see if setting `ESCAPED BY` to something other than a backslash will help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to replace your field separator \ by a pipe |

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/anilyelin/Desktop/cars.csv'
INTO TABLE specs
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```